# add button inside viewpager fragment and intent in another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-studio

I'm trying to create an app which will display my menu and I use `viewpager` fragment for display and I want to add a button for every page of the `viewpager` which will intent to another activity can someone help me for this?

This is my viewpager:

```
public class menu_meat_viewer extends FragmentActivity{

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.meat_viewer);


        initialisePaging();
    }

    private void initialisePaging(){

        List<Fragment> fragments=new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, meat_adobo.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, meat_bbqpork.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, meat_tlshrmp.class.getName()));

        mPagerAdapter=new menu_meat_viewer_adapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.meat_view);
        pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }



}
```

and this is one of my page in view pager:

```
public class meat_adobo extends Fragment{

    int price= 70;
    String name="classic chicken adobo";

    MDB mdb;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(container==null){
            return null;
        }
        return(RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.meat_adobo,container,false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a button in your fragment layout 
and
Add this code to your fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meat_adobo, container, false);
    Button b=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 Intent in=new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);

            }
        });

    return v;
    }
```

and add `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`